# Adding tag's featured image to tag archive

Tags: taxonomy, tags, archives, sidebar, taxonomy-meta

I'm looking for a way to add a featured image to post tags, then display it on that tag's archive page.

I currently have the name and description displayed in the sidebar, using a custom sidebar location that only targets the tag archive; the PHP Code widget and the following snippet:

```
<h2 class="archive-title-sidebar">Everything about:</h2>
<h1 class="archive-title-sidebar"><?php echo get_the_archive_title()?></h1>
<?php echo the_archive_description('<div class="archive-description">','</div>')?>
```

So essentially what I'm looking for is a way to display that tag's featured image in addition to the title and description.

Thanks so much in advance,

Julian

Comment: Just use the [Categories Images plugin](http://zahlan.net/blog/2012/06/categories-images/)... Then is so easy to add images to tags or categories and display it.